# Unable to parse date while inserting data in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am unable to migrate date in Elasticsearch 6. My date example is:

```
Fri, 21 Apr 2017 01:58:20 GMT
```

I have tried this without success:

```
"date": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "E, d MMM Y H:m:s z"
}
```

Please help.